# How to identify which app is causing the notification LED to flash?

Tags: lg, lg-g4, notification-led, diagnostics

My LG G4's notification LED has started intermittently flashing yellow for unknown reasons.

Normally, I would assume that a notification is causing it, but in this case, no notifications are present and clearing the existing ones doesn't stop the flashing. I have not (knowingly) set an app to flash either.

Is there a way to diagnose which app is causing the flashing?